# python pyautogui working together with pynput

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

The subject is next, I´m doing some siple clickers with pyautogui but it lacks of control. Basically I want to be able to start and stop different scripts based on pyautogui. My idea was to combine the Listener function from pynput, but it doesn´t work properly . It starts when I press the assigned key, but I cannot stop it, why?
Here is some simle code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener
import time
import pyautogui as pg
pg.FAILSAFE = True
kb = Controller()
time.sleep(1)
def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.space:
        pg.position(500, 500)
        x = 20
        while key is not Key.enter:
            pg.moveRel(x, 0, duration=0.2)
            time.sleep(1)



with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I also have tried this loop:

```
while True:
    if key==Key.enter:
        pg.moveRel(x, 0, duration=0.2)
    else:
        return(False)
    time.sleep(1)
```

but nothing works.

UPD:
Maybe someone can suggest me another module with controlling features, which can be good for clicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing to stop because you are in a infinite loop when you do this:

```
while key is not Key.enter:
```

due to the fact that your on_press can't be called again and therefore the variable *key* will never change.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener
import time
import pyautogui as pg


import threading

pg.FAILSAFE = True
kb = Controller()
time.sleep(1)

threadExitFlag = threading.Event()
threadVar = None


def mouse_move_thread(threadExitFlag):
    pg.position(500, 500)
    x = 20
    while not threadExitFlag.is_set():
        pg.moveRel(x, 0, duration=0.2)
        time.sleep(1)

def on_press(key):
    global threadExitFlag

    if key == Key.space:
        threadVar = threading.Thread(target=mouse_move_thread, args=[threadExitFlag]).start()
    if key == Key.enter:
        threadExitFlag.set()

    #Turns this macro back on
    elif key == Key.esc:
        if threadExitFlag.is_set():
            threadExitFlag.clear()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

To use this, you press space to start your mouse movement, then you can stop it by pressing enter. After this, you need to press *esc key* to reset the event that stops it which means to do this macro twice in a row you need to press:

```
space (start the macro)
enter (stop/kill the macro)
esc (reset flag, if you press space after this you can start the macro again)
```

I've tested it and it works 100%.

Comment: You are right. I just need to avoid looping it... Thank you.

Comment: I've literally never used python threading prior to this but I updated my post with a method that should work for you.